# Laravel dusk with browserstack to run tests on multiple devices and browsers

Tags: laravel, automated-tests, browserstack, laravel-dusk, browser-testing

I am using this ("browserstack/browserstack-local": "^1.1") package to run dusk tests on BrowserStack. Now the requirement is to run tests on multiple and different devices with different browsers. Currently, I am following this approach to run tests.

```
private function browserStackCaps($local_identifier)
{
    return [
        'project' => config('app.name'),
        'browserstack.local' => 'true',
        'browser' => env('BROWSER'),
        'device' => env('DEVICE'),
        'acceptSslCert' => true,
        'resolution' => '1920x1080'
    ];
}
```

The drawback of this approach is I have to change the device name and browser name in the .env file every time I need to run tests on a different device/browser. Is there any way I can run tests on the provided array? The array that contains devices and browser information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old, but I found this page while searching for a solution. I ended up building one myself that would probably meet your use-case. The biggest hurdle that I had was `$this->browse()` in a normal Dusk test was using a single instance of `Laravel\Dusk\Browser` and the new capabilities were not being pulled in. This implementation adds a function called `performTest` to the DuskTestCase.php file. This function loops through a set of capabilities and instantiates a new instance of `Laravel\Dusk\Browser` for each test. This function works similarly to the existing `browse` function in Laravel Dusk. You call `performTest` by passing it a callable that accepts a single parameter which is an instance of `Laravel\Dusk\Browser`

**Dusk Test Case**

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Laravel\Dusk\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;

abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
    protected array $capabilities;

    private const BROWSERS = [
        'ios_14_iphone_xs_safari' => [
            "os_version" => "14",
            "device" => "iPhone XS",
            "real_mobile" => "true",
            "browserstack.local" => "true",
            'acceptSslCerts' => 'true'                
        ],
        'mac_osx_catalina_safari' => [
            "os" => "OS X",
            "os_version" => "Catalina",
            "browser" => "Safari",
            "browser_version" => "13.0",
            "browserstack.local" => "true",
            "browserstack.selenium_version" => "3.14.0",
            "resolution" => "1920x1080",
            'acceptSslCerts' => 'true',
        ]
    ];



    /**
     * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected function driver()
    {
        $browserStackConnectionUrl = config('browserstack.connection_url');
        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            $browserStackConnectionUrl, $this->capabilities
        );
    }

    protected function performTest(Callable $test){
        foreach(self::BROWSERS as $browserName => $capabilitySet){
            try {
                $this->capabilities = $capabilitySet;
                $browser = $this->newBrowser($this->driver());
                $test($browser);
                $browser->quit();
                fprintf(STDOUT, "\e[0;32m√ {$browserName}\r\n");
            }
            catch(\Exception $exception){
                fprintf(STDOUT, "\e[0;31mX {$browserName}\r\n");
                throw $exception;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**Example Test**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;

class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->performTest(function(Browser $browser){
            $browser->visit('/')
                ->assertDontSee('Foobar');
        });
    }
}
```

**config/browserstack.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'connection_url' => env('BROWSERSTACK_CONNECTION_URL')
];
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris, this solution is quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement this at your end. Fetch the list of Browsers and Devices you want to execute your tests on using the REST API and use the same.

REST API to be  used:

curl -u "username:password" 
https://api.browserstack.com/automate/browsers.json

Read more on this here:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/api-reference/selenium/browser#get-browser-list

Comment: Sorry if I am unable to explain my question properly. I already have a list of browsers and devices on which I want to execute tests. But I don't know how to to use that list as a source for #dusk.

Comment: I want to run same test on different devices and for that, I have to run command one by one after changing the browser name or OS in caps array but now I want a way to give more than one combinations of browsers and devices as an array so I wouldn't have to run one by one.